# CSS - .firstclass td .secondclass does not work

Tags: css, html-table

I have a problem with styling my table with class selectors.

I want two different colors, one for the `th` element with the class="pause" and another color on the `td` element with the same class name.

Why does this CSS not work:

```
.timetable th .pause {
    background-color:#F99;
}
.timetable td .pause {
    background-color:#FEE;  
}
```

on this HTML?

```
<table class="timetable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Tispunkt</th>
                <th style='height:30px;'>08:00</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>08:30</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>09:00</th>
        <th style='height:15px;'>09:30</th>
        <th style='height:15px;' class='pause'>09:45</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>10:00</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>10:30</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>11:00</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>11:30</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>12:00</th>
        <th style='height:30px;' class='pause'>12:30</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>13:00</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>13:30</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>14:00</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>14:30</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>15:00</th>
        <th style='height:30px;'>15:30</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Maskine 4</td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:15px;'></td>
        <td style='height:15px;' class='pause'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;' class='pause'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
        <td style='height:30px;'></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This CSS works

```
.timetable .pause {
    background-color:#F99;  
}
```

But I want to different colors on `th` elements and `td` elements

Comment: [Remove the space before `.pause`](http://jsfiddle.net/PrZm8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following:

```
.timetable th.pause {
    background-color:#F99;
}
.timetable td.pause {
    background-color:#FEE;  
}
```

No space between the tag and the class name.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. I did not know that there could not be spaces between the tag and the class name. If I have a space, then it would work on an element inside the tag? example <div class="pause">, if it is inside the tag?

Comment: Indeed, that is the case.  The space between the tag and the class implies a parent - child relationship.  No space means: "the tag with the class"